# Minecraft disconnection timeout, aiding bad connection players

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a friend who has horrible connection issues and gets Timed Out of my server. I was wondering if there was a way to extend the amount of time before he gets kicked off the server.

Minecraft client and server version: 1.7.10, using Forge Mod Loader version 7.99.16.1448.

This is the Timed Out error he is receiving.

> [12:49:52] [Server thread/INFO]: EAT FOOD lost connection:
>   TextComponent{text='Disconnected', siblings=[],
>   style=Style{hasParent=false, color=null, bold=null, italic=null,
>   underlined=null, obfuscated=null, clickEvent=null, hoverEvent=null}}

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! :D
What version are you running? What sort of issues do they get? Please add more info.

Comment: Aid in what way?  Is there a specific problem you are trying to counter? What type of server is this? This question seems too broad and recommendation-based.

Comment: Bear in mind that even if the timeout delay is extended, and he's just obscenely laggy rather than actually disconnecting, this still won't make his connection better. It'll just stop disconnecting him.

Comment: I have this problem on my own computer, and there is nothing you can do really.

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft has a built in timer, because if a player tries to connect for too long, it will lag the server. You could go into his computer and change the files, but it would no longer be compatible with servers. However, if there was some way to play in a better internet connection, or get a better computer, this would solve the issue. Otherwise, there is no way to do it.